# Integer Overflow com PID em C

Tags: c

Olá. Estou tentando implementar um programa em C (para 3DS) que gere processos e termine-os até conseguir gerar um Integer Overflow no PID para que seja 0, mas não sei exatamente como fazer isso. Qual seria o jeito mais fácil?

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia seria criar um laço fazendo fork(). Algo como:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
...
int p;
for (p = 0; p < INT_MAX; p++) {
  int status;
  if (!fork()) { // processo filho
    sleep(1); // dormir um tempinho para que o pid nao seja reaproveitado
    exit(0);
  }
  wait(&status, WNOHANG);
}
```

Eu não testei o código, mas acho você precisará do wait(), senão você acabará com um trilhão de processos zumbis. Talvez vc precise também reduzir o tempo do sleep(), substituindo-o por um usleep(), para não ter mais processos simultâneos do que sua máquina suporta.